# How to replace a character if there are characters either side of it?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I've been playing around with a bit of regular expression in Python and I got stuck when I was trying to replace `"b"` in string `A` *if* `"b"` has any character either side of it. Example:

- Replace `"b"`: `"aaabaaa"`
- Do not replace `"b"`: `"aaa b aaa"`

Regular expressions don't seem to come very easy to me, so how would I do this?

Comment: Can you give better eg. ? The examples you have given are bit ambiguous. Make clear what you call A and what you call "b".

Comment: And what about "aaa bbb aaa" ?

Comment: It's not clear what your rules are, but I suggest you look into *"lookarounds"*.

Comment: Someone has answered this perfectly. I didn't need to explain much, I just needed to know which regex escape to use. I couldn't find it on Google or the Python docs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use non word boundary.

```
re.sub(r'\Bb\B', '', s)
```

`\B` (*matches between two word chars or two non-word chars*) does the opposite of `\b` (*matches between a word char and a non-word char vice-versa*)

Comment: This works, thank you very much! This was exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds too.

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\w)b(?=\w)','',s)
```

here `(?<=\w)b(?=\w)` looks for `b` that have word character before and after using look around construct.
e.g

```
>>>s = 'aaabaaa b wr'
>>>re.sub(r'(?<=\w)b(?=\w)','',s)
>>>'aaaaaa b wr'
```